# Largest Triangular Number less than a Given Natural Number

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, number-theory

I want to determine the closest Triangular number a particular natural number is.  For example, the first 10 triangular numbers are $1,3,6,10,15,21,28,36,45,55$ and thus, the number $57$ can be written as 
$$57=T_{10}+2$$
The number $54$ can be written as
$$54=T_{9}+9\neq T_{10}-1$$
The second part highlights that I am looking for Triangular numbers larger than a particular positive, and not necessarily "closer" in terms of distance from Triangular numbers.

My approach would be this; given the $n$-th Triangular number has the formula
$$T_n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\binom{n+1}{2}$$
If I'm looking for a particular breakdown and close Triangular number, my number, say, $M$ will be of the form
$$M=T_k+r$$
where $0\le r\le k$, and thus
$$2(M-r)=k^2+k$$
And thus
$$k=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1+8(M-r)}}{2}$$
I'm lost here in trying to solve, given that $r$ varies.  I know that $r$ is less than or equal to $k$ but for sufficiently large $M$, how would I go about finishing solving?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

$\binom{k}{2}\leq n$ is equivalent to $(2k-1)^2 \leq 8n+1$, hence the largest triangular number $\leq n$ is given by $\binom{k}{2}$ with:
$$ k = \left\lfloor \frac{1+\sqrt{8n+1}}{2}\right\rfloor.$$

Comment: That was easier than I anticipated...should have known that you could floor out the $r$.  Thanks!

Comment: I think it should be $\binom{k+1}{2}\le n$ is equivalent to $(2k+1)^2\le 8n+1$...

Comment: @Lalaloopsy: it is exactly the same, you are just replacing my $k$ with your $k+1$.

Comment: But then if say, $n=4, k=3$.  Since I defined $T_k=\binom{k+1}{2}$, this would mean that $T_3=6\le 4$...

Comment: So, just a semantical argument and either way works....right?

Comment: I think @Lalaloopsy 's inequality is correct and the final result is k=$\lceil\frac{-1+\sqrt{8n+1}}{2}\rceil$.

Comment: @user2582713 yes, with floor instead of ceiling, though